# How do you add Invoke methods to a custom control?

Tags: wpf, controls, invoke

I have a custom control progressbar, that I need to update through another thread.. There doesn't seem to be an Invoke, BeginInvoke, InvokeRequired etc available to a custom control, does anyone have any ideas on how to implement this within the control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to look at the `Dispatcher.Invoke` method to do this. I have a handy method that wraps this functionality for me:

```
public object RunOnUiThread(Delegate method)
{
    return Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, method);
}
```

I use it like this:

```
UiThreadManager.RunOnUiThread((Action)delegate
{
    // This code will run on the UI thread
});
```

Note that you will need to use the correct `Dispatcher` object from the UI thread and not one that is created on a non-UI thread. Please take look at the [`Dispatcher.Invoke` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx) page on MSDN for more information on this.

Please let me know if this is not what you were after.

Comment: Hi Sheridan, This is close, I would like to wrap them so they preserve the same call signature as seen on other controls, so maybe? public object Invoke(Delegate method)
{
    return Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, method);
} But how would I wrap RequiresInvoke in the same way?

Comment: Sorry, but what does that mean?